# Chrome saves autofill data from another computer

Tags: google-chrome, skype, teamviewer

Recently I had some conversation with a coworker and we ware using Skype desktop share and TeamViewer. I saw that I have his username, bank account email and etc (in short: auto-fill data) in my browser (Google Chrome) without even typing them. He did not typed any of his auto-fill data in my browser but I have them.

I do not talk about passwords, just the input text boxes.

Does TeamViewer or Skype send them? Every time I use TeamViewer and Skype I end up with auto-fill data that does not belong to me.

How is that possible?

Comment: No;  Neither program would submit Chrome data. You received this data from some other action.

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged into both browsers using your google account? If you are you'll see a little name like this in the upper right hand corner:

[image: Google Account Pic]

This will transfer data, including history, autofill and cookies across computers.

Comment: Nope, I'm not logged in his browser. He did not logged in in mine.

Comment: It is very strange thing. My coworker was showing me (with teamviever) one website and there was his iban number inside one input field. On the next day when I was doing registration on that website my browser suggested me his iban